# Bug with Mod Diamonds on Chrome on Windows 10

Tags: bug, status-norepro

The mod diamonds on Chrome on Windows 10 have suddenly a lot bigger - but clicking "Show X more comments" they revert to what they should be.

This is Chrome 56 on Windows 10

Doesn't happen in Firefox or Edge.

@CodyGray reports Chrome on Windows 7 doesn't have this

[image]

It seems that before you click show more the diamond is shown using:

```
<svg style="padding: 0; margin: 0; width:100%; height:100%;"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#emoji-2666"></use></svg>
```

But after by using:

```
<span class="mod-flair" title="moderator">♦</span>
```

Comment: There isn't supposed to be a "big" version. That is the actual bug here. I can't repro that in Chrome on Windows 7 or Firefox on Windows 10. (Don't happen to have Chrome on Windows 10.)

Comment: @CodyGray yes just realized that after testing Firefox and Edge

Comment: @CodyGray updated

Comment: Chrome 56.0.2924.87, Windows 10 - no repro. Do you happen to be zoomed in or something?

Comment: `<span class="mod-flair" title="moderator">♦</span>` is what I get before and after clicking.

Comment: @Oded no not zoomed in, guess it must be local config error then

Comment: Looks like SO created a new motto.  Walk softly and carry a big diamond.

Comment: Chrome 56.0.2924.87, Windows 10 - no repro here also

Comment: Wondering if this is an extension/add-on you have.